# ASP.net MVC Form post security

Tags: asp.net, validation, model-view-controller

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.I made some validations for my model

`[Required]
 [EmailAdress]`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
{

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

//Controller

```
[HTTPPOST]
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //Approved 
    return View();
}
//Not approved
return View();
```

But when I edit html with F12 and add other empty form. Its posting without any model validation
How can I defend this

Comment: What about backend validation? `if (!ModelState.IsValid)`

Comment: I checked for if (ModelState.IsValid) not for not valid